# Append an object in openstack swift

Tags: openstack-swift

Is it possible to append an already existing file/object in open stack swift.
If Yes, which version of swift supports it.

Also is it possible to boost the read/write performance in swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your first question is no.  You cannot append to an existing object in Object Storage.  You can only replace the object that is there.

The answer to your second question is too broad and vague to be answered in this forum.

Comment: And does that hold true for all the available versions of Swift?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge.  The fundamental unit of writing data into an object store is the object itself.  There is no concept of accessing the data in the object with any finer granularity.

Comment: What should be the optimum file size to be stored in Swift. I understand that it is not suited for too many small files like HDFS, becuase that increases the memory occupied by inodes.